# Visual studio 2012/2015 messes up my .net framework installation on windows 10 LTSB

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have installed Microsoft Visual studio 2012 Pro on Windows 10 LTSB however after the installation was done I could no longer run any application that needed .net 3.0 or later, I ran a .net framework detection tool and it didn't detect anything over framework 2.0.

I tried running a .net framework 4.0/4.5 installation but it always said that these versions were already installed on Windows 10. Tried a registry hack to change the .net version but to no avail.

In the end I had to reinstall windows, I tried installing VS again but got exactly the same problem, however I turned system restore on so I could revert back.

Do you have any idea what could be causing this problem and how it can be fixed?

To be more specific, every application that was based on .net 2.0 or later would give me the same error thus the VS installation corrupts or replaces the .NET framework with one that doesn't work.
The error message was the application was unable to start correctly then an error 0xc00000135

EDIT:
I tried 2015 as-well, same error.

Answer (score 3):

You can add app.config side .exe file
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't understand how this is going to help as once I installed VS, the .NET installation would get corrupted.
The app would call the .NET runtime, but the runtime would give me an error.

Comment: I think if you force the .NET framework version for application used .NET 2.0 it will fixe the error